# Ошибка: undefined reference to QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, lib

Пишу свою статическую библиотеку, в ней использую библиотеку loping, ниже будет показано, как я это делаю. Библиотека собирается, а вот когда хочу её потестить на каком нибудь проекте выдает ошибки /home/danila/Qt/Projects/ADTLib/LIN/ADTNode.cpp:-1: ошибка: undefined reference to `ping_construct' и т.д. на  каждую функцию из loping. Как такое можно исправить. Ниже приведен код pro файлов

pro файл моей библиотеки

```
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++11

CONFIG += adtlib

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

win32 {
    SOURCES += WIN\ADTComponent.cpp
    SOURCES += WIN\ADTNode.cpp
    LIBS += -lws2_32
    LIBS += -liphlpapi
}

unix {
    SOURCES += LIN/ADTComponent.cpp
    SOURCES += LIN/ADTNode.cpp
    LIBS += -loping
}

HEADERS += \
    include/ADTComponent.h \
    include/ADTNode.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

pro файл проекта в котором тестирую либу

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

INCLUDEPATH += /home/danila/Qt/Projects/ADTLib/include
LIBS += /home/danila/Qt/Projects/build-ADTLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Release/libADTLib.a
```

реализация функции которая использует функции из oping - относится к моей либе

```
bool pingToHost(QString host)
{
  bool res = false;

      pingobj_t *pingobj = ping_construct();

      int timeout = 4;
      for (;;)
        {
          double timeout_sec = ((double)timeout)/(double)(1000.0);

          if (ping_setopt(pingobj, PING_OPT_TIMEOUT, &timeout_sec))
            break;

          if (ping_host_add(pingobj, host.toStdString().c_str()))
            break;

          if (ping_send(pingobj) <= 0)
            break;

          res = true;

          break;
        }

      ping_destroy(pingobj);

      return res;
}
```

ну и пример как проверяю

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <ADTNode.h>
#include <ADTComponent.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  pingToHost("127.0.0.1");

  return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `oping` (и прочие динамические зависимости вашей библиотеки) прилинковать к проекту, который использует вашу статическую библиотеку, так как к статической бибилиотеки ничего прилинковать нельзя, ведь это просто пачка объектных файлов, а не исполняемый модуль.
2. собрать `oping` как статическую библиотеку и объединить с вашей

Comment: изменил pro файл там где тестирую ```LIBS += /opt/oping/lib/liboping.a
INCLUDEPATH += /home/danila/Qt/Projects/ADTLib/include``` добавил эти строки, как собрать oping как статическую ?

Comment: @DanBit Это два альтернативных способа, а не два шага одного способа.